# How to Align Arabic Characters Vertically with Robot-Serif Font in CSS/TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an alignment issue with Arabic characters when using the Robot-Serif font. Despite my efforts using both TailwindCSS and standard CSS, I can't seem to get the characters to align correctly in the vertical space.

Here's what the misalignment looks like:

[image: Arabic Letters not aligned]

The alignment problem appears to stem from how the font renders different Arabic characters at varying vertical positions. Some characters are placed at the top, while others are centered along the Y-axis. This inconsistency is problematic as shown here:

[image: arabic letters missaligment with selection]

Inspecting the issue, it's noticeable that the vertical spacing for some characters is too large, and their vertical positioning varies significantly. I've attempted to standardize the alignment with CSS, but to no avail.

Could anyone advise on how to achieve consistent vertical alignment for Arabic characters in this font?

Comment: Is it actually *incorrect*? That would sound like a broken font then. I don’t really read Arabic, but from the little I do know about it, this looks perfectly fine‽ Some characters simply do drop below the baseline, and others don’t; just like “g” vs. “f”. Can you perhaps highlight more clearly where exactly you see the problem?

Comment: It's not actually incorrect, whenever writting the arabic letters there is a line, some letters are written under it some are over it, for the purposes of this html document I would like to have them in the same line if possible.

Comment: So you want to arbitrarily dislodge them for arbitrary design purposes? Then you can probably only manually shift each one by some amount you need to figure out manually…

Comment: Yes, I could do it manually but I don’t want to, that’s the purpose of the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can give line height css property for this text
or by making vertical-align:bottom

line-height: normal;
vertical-align: bottom;

or whatever you want to set in this value ,you can set line height in pixels too

Hope this will help